# modify iptables rules and default policy but keeping port forwarding

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have the following rules and policy in the end of my firewall script:

```
$IPT=/sbin/iptables
...
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -F FORWARD


# Forward port 2206 to data6 
$IPT -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 6X.XXX.XXX.YY7 -p tcp --destination-port 2206 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2206 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:22

# accept port 22 for the machine 192.168.1.2
$IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT --protocol tcp --destination 192.168.1.2 --destination-port 22
```

With these rules I can ssh directly to the host `192.168.1.2` with `ssh 192.168.1.2` or with
`ssh -p 2206 6X.XXX.XXX.YY7`.

I would like change the default forward policy from `ACCEPT` to `DROP`. However, when I tried this I had no access to the host `192.168.1.2`.

Should I worry about the default accept policy?
How do I adapt the rules to work with the policy `DROP`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the default policy to DROP then you need to allow the traffic to come back from 192.168.1.2:22 through the firewall.

```
$IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED
$IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 22
```

It may also be necessary to allow reverse DNS lookups by adding :

```
$IPT -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p udp -s 192.168.1.2 --dport 53
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave the default policy as is and simply add `$IPT -A FORWARD -j DROP` to the end of the script to effectively drop anything that wasn't previously matched.